# What would be the average distance between each 1-degree latitude on Jupiter?

Tags: distances, jupiter

Do planets like Jupiter have a system of latitudes and longitudes (I believe yes)? So if yes, what purpose do they serve? Is there anything different in their purpose from Earth lat-longs? and What would be the average distance between each 1-degree latitude on Jupiter?

Comment: You can calculate this easily enough by looking up the diameter of Jupiter (and, if necessary, the definition of a degree of latitude or  longitude)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I wasn't sure on how to go about calculating this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they have coordinate systems as well. For example, the Wikipedia page on the [Great Red Spot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Red_Spot) mentions it lies 22 degrees south of the planet's equator. Jupiter has a polar radius of 66,854 km; a latitude degree is $2 \pi / 360$ times that, so almost 1,167 km.

Note that because Jupiter lacks a solid surface, longitudes are less well-defined. In fact, there are [three different systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Jupiter#Great_Red_Spot) for this:

> Because Jupiter's visible features do not rotate uniformly at all latitudes, astronomers have defined three different systems for defining the longitude.

Rocky planets like Mars do have a well-defined coordinate system, as shown in [this map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars#/media/File:USGS-MarsMap-sim3292-20140714-crop.png) and on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quadrangles_on_Mars).

These coordinates are used to mark and find interesting places on either the surface (like on Earth) or in the atmosphere of a planet. There are also tables available showing which latitude/longitude is directed towards us at a certain moment, so that you can compute whether a particular region of the planet is visible from Earth or not.